# Remove Google Marker using Lat or Long

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary, google-maps-markers

I want to remove Marker using Lat or Long values. I have created a remove Marker function which removes the marker that exists on map.

Comment: Before posting your question please first  google it,you will get answer i'm sure. If you failed no problem  we are here to help you always.

Comment: i do it 
 http://jsfiddle.net/3qw8d/

Comment: I am already do google. bt i amm very confused that time .. i am share link plz help
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3qw8d/)

Answer (score 0):

While removing marker from google map , just set `setMap(null)` ,

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
         var marker;
         var map;
        function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: myLatlng
            };
           map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
           marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Hello World!'
            });

        }
        function removeMarker(lat,long)
        {
            marker.setMap(null); //no need to set marker again - so removed
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>

<body>
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" id="map-canvas"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="removeMarker(-25.363882, 131.044922)" value="Remove" />
</body>
```